# Is moving documents between collections a good way to represent state changes in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections, one (**A**) containing items to be processed (relatively small) and one (**B**) with those already processed (fairly large, with extra result fields).

Items are read from **A**, get processed and save()'d to **B**, then remove()'d from **A**.

The rationale is that indices can be different across these, and that the "incoming" collection can be kept very small and fast this way.

I've run into two issues with this:

- if either remove() or save() time out or otherwise fail under load, I lose the item completely, or process it twice
- if both fail, the side effects happen but there is no record of that

I can sidestep the double-failure case with findAndModify locks (not needed otherwise, we have a process-level lock) but then we have stale lock issues and partial failures can still happen. There's no way to atomically remove+save to different collections, as far as I can tell (maybe by design?)

Is there a Best Practice for this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There's no way to atomically remove+save to different collections, as far as I can tell (maybe by design?)

Yes this is by design. MongoDB explicitly does not provides joins or transactions. Remove + Save is a form of transaction.

> Is there a Best Practice for this situation?

You really have two low-complexity options here, both involve `findAndModify`.

**Option #1: a single collection**

Based on your description, you are basically building a queue with some extra features. If you leverage a single collection then you use `findAndModify` to update the status of each item as it is processing.

Unfortunately, that means you will lose this: *...that the "incoming" collection can be kept very small and fast this way*.

**Option #2: two collections**

The other option is basically a two phase commit, leveraging `findAndModify`.

Take a look at the docs for this [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/two-phase+commit).

Once an item is processed in *A* you set a field to flag it for deletion. You then copy that item over to *B*. Once copied to *B* you can then remove the item from *A*.

Comment: I actually arrived at essentially a simpler version of the two-phase commit with rollbacks implementation after scratching my head some more, glad to know it's the Official Way :) Single-collection locking doesn't quite work because of the different ways the to-be- vs already-processed items are used (findAndModify recursive/non-yielding locks would be very bad here). Two-phase it is!

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried this myself yet but the new book 50 Tips and Tricks for MongoDB Developers mentions a few times about using cron jobs (or services/scheduler) to clean up data like this. You could leave the documents in Collection A flagged for deletion and run daily job to clear them out, reducing the overall scope of the original transaction.

From what I've learned so far, I'd never leave the database in a state where I rely on the next database action succeeding unless it is the *last* action (journalling will resend the last db action upon recovery). For example, I have a three phase account registration process where I create a user in CollectionA and then add another related document to CollectionB. When I create the user I embed the details of the CollectionB document in CollectionA in case the second write fails. Later I will write a process that removes the embedded data from CollectionA if the document in CollectionB exists

Not having transactions does cause pain points like this, but I think in some cases there are new ways of thinking about it. In my case, time will tell as I progress with my app

Comment: You know, reading my own comment it seems an unsatisfactory solution. Creating a new account is one of the most critical parts of a web application and in my case it is unavoidably a multi-step update. I am considering using dapper to sql express or mysql for the core system. And for reporting/archiving/forum I would use mongo

Comment: Running cleanup cronjobs and hiding backups inside other structures doesn't quite seem like a clean solution (though I can't think of a better one for your case -- rolling back user creation isn't really an option -- other than the slight variant of writing as a "job" item to collection C first, then building entries in A and B and removing/marking C, with unique indices on A/B)

Comment: Ah you mean something like a collection (C) of jobs that need to run, and a flag to state the stage they're at so they can be completed cleanly. None of this seems clean to me either which is why I'm beginning to veer away from Mongo for this particular project