# mongodb move documents from one collection to another collection

Tags: mongodb

How can **documents** be **moved from one collection to another collection** in **MongoDB**?? For example: I have lot of documents in collection A and I want to move all 1 month older documents to collection B (these 1 month older documents should not be in collection A).

Using **aggregation** we can do **copy**. But what I am trying to do is **moving** of documents.
What method can be used to move documents?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Update 2**

Please do NOT upvote this answer any more. As written [@jasongarber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41483981/1296707) is better in every aspect.

**Update**

[This answer by @jasongarber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41483981/1296707) is a safer approach and should be used instead of mine.

---

Provided I got you right and you want to move all documents older than 1 month, and you use mongoDB 2.6, there is no reason not to use bulk operations, which are the most efficient way of doing multiple operations I am aware of:

```
> var bulkInsert = db.target.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
> var bulkRemove = db.source.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
> var date = new Date()
> date.setMonth(date.getMonth() -1)
> db.source.find({"yourDateField":{$lt: date}}).forEach(
    function(doc){
      bulkInsert.insert(doc);
      bulkRemove.find({_id:doc._id}).removeOne();
    }
  )
> bulkInsert.execute()
> bulkRemove.execute()
```

This should be pretty fast and it has the advantage that in case something goes wrong during the bulk insert, the original data still exists.

---

**Edit**

In order to prevent too much memory to be utilized, you can execute the bulk operation on every `x` docs processed:

```
> var bulkInsert = db.target.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
> var bulkRemove = db.source.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
> var x = 10000
> var counter = 0
> var date = new Date()
> date.setMonth(date.getMonth() -1)
> db.source.find({"yourDateField":{$lt: date}}).forEach(
    function(doc){
      bulkInsert.insert(doc);
      bulkRemove.find({_id:doc._id}).removeOne();
      counter ++
      if( counter % x == 0){
        bulkInsert.execute()
        bulkRemove.execute()
        bulkInsert = db.target.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
        bulkRemove = db.source.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
      }
    }
  )
> bulkInsert.execute()
> bulkRemove.execute()
```

Comment: Or in UI tools like Robomongo 
db.getCollection('source').find({}).forEach(function(doc) { db.getCollection('target').insert(doc); 
db.getCollection('source').remove(doc);})

Comment: @Arthur: Your approach has two major drawbacks. It is *much* slower *and* you might have incomplete collections hard to synchronize again in a worst case scenario.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I tried this on a collection with 50M records, and tried to move about 25M out.  It failed on the find query with the error `Fatal error in CALL_AND_RETRY_2 # Allocation failed - process out of memory`.  This is on a server with 32GB of memory, and the records only had 5 fields.  The total data size of the collection is only about 5GB.

Comment: Do you mean put a limit on the find query?  I didn't even execute anything, The out of mem error happened during the foreach.  If the bulk features can only deal with 10k chunks then they are not really fit for purpose :/ (Sorry, not venting at you, and I appreciate your help, just feeling a bit frustrated!)

Comment: @UpTheCreek See edit. And I just want to rule out that we have a memory problem. Because it sounds like that. Possibly imposed by the OS.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg - thanks - I'll try that as soon as I can and report back.  (BTW, I'm on debian 8, with `ulimit -m unlimited`)

Comment: ICYMI, I published this code as NPM package - https://github.com/vladgolubev/mongo-move

Answer (score 120):

The bulk operations @markus-w-mahlberg showed (and @mark-mullin refined) are efficient but unsafe as written. If the bulkInsert fails, the bulkRemove will still continue. To make sure you don't lose any records when moving, use this instead:

```js
function insertBatch(collection, documents) {
  var bulkInsert = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
  var insertedIds = [];
  var id;
  documents.forEach(function(doc) {
    id = doc._id;
    // Insert without raising an error for duplicates
    bulkInsert.find({_id: id}).upsert().replaceOne(doc);
    insertedIds.push(id);
  });
  bulkInsert.execute();
  return insertedIds;
}

function deleteBatch(collection, documents) {
  var bulkRemove = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
  documents.forEach(function(doc) {
    bulkRemove.find({_id: doc._id}).removeOne();
  });
  bulkRemove.execute();
}

function moveDocuments(sourceCollection, targetCollection, filter, batchSize) {
  print("Moving " + sourceCollection.find(filter).count() + " documents from " + sourceCollection + " to " + targetCollection);
  var count;
  while ((count = sourceCollection.find(filter).count()) > 0) {
    print(count + " documents remaining");
    sourceDocs = sourceCollection.find(filter).limit(batchSize);
    idsOfCopiedDocs = insertBatch(targetCollection, sourceDocs);

    targetDocs = targetCollection.find({_id: {$in: idsOfCopiedDocs}});
    deleteBatch(sourceCollection, targetDocs);
  }
  print("Done!")
}
```

Comment: This procedure keeps the id in target and source.
(my case is a bit differnt than the post, and i stumbled over this feature.)

Comment: asynchronous update to this posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715607/7583056

Comment: Can you provide an example of run moveDocuments?

Comment: Something important to note is that this does _not_ free the space from the source collection.

Comment: Is this mongosh? 
Very cool solution. Mission now is to rewrite this in pymongo.

Comment: moveDocuments(db.collectionA, db.collectionB, {'some.nested.param': 'value'}, 100);

Comment: This code is not atomic either.  If deleteBatch fails the documents will still have been copied to the destination collection by insertBatch.

Comment: This solution fails in a sharded cluster with the following message being emitted by each document: `Failed to target upsert by query :: could not extract exact shard key`

Comment: Revisiting this question and both your and my answer, I am not too sure anymore whether you are correct with your assessment. Should a problem with `bulkInsert.execute()` come up, you would not necessarily run `bulkRemove.execute()`, would you? Note that I made clear that I was using the CLI by prepending `>`.

Answer (score 23):

Insert and remove:

```
var documentsToMove = db.collectionA.find({});
documentsToMove.forEach(function(doc) {
    db.collectionB.insert(doc);
    db.collectionA.remove(doc);
});
```

note: this method might be quite slow for large collections or collections holding large documents.

Comment: Is insert() and remove() the optimized solution to do ??

Comment: No idea :) You could also dump and restore using the admin tools.

Comment: This is not atomic , there is a potential of something being inserted in Collection B and not being removed from A.

Comment: The very last line should be `});` instead of just `}`. Closing parenthesis is missing.

Answer (score 13):

$out is use to create the new collection with data , so use $out

```
db.oldCollection.aggregate([{$out : "newCollection"}])
```

then use drop

```
db.oldCollection.drop()
```

Comment: Bare in mind this will OVERWRITE the whole collection if it already exists with that name (instead of appending the matched documents from the old one)!

Answer (score 5):

you can use range query to get data from sourceCollection and keep the cursor data in variable and loop on it and insert to target collection:

```
 var doc = db.sourceCollection.find({
        "Timestamp":{
              $gte:ISODate("2014-09-01T00:00:00Z"),
              $lt:ISODate("2014-10-01T00:00:00Z")
        }
 });

 doc.forEach(function(doc){
    db.targetCollection.insert(doc);
 })
```

Hope so it helps!!

Comment: Yeahhhh!! Is insert() and remove() the optimized solution to do ??

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942575/is-moving-documents-between-collections-a-good-way-to-represent-state-changes-in

Answer (score 5):

Here's an update to @jasongarber's answer which uses the more recent mongo 'bulkWrite' operation [(Read docs here)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-updateonemany), and also keeps the whole process asynchronous so you can run it as part of a wider script which depends on its' completion.

```
async function moveDocuments (sourceCollection, targetCollection, filter) {
  const sourceDocs = await sourceCollection.find(filter)

  console.log(`Moving ${await sourceDocs.count()} documents from ${sourceCollection.collectionName} to ${targetCollection.collectionName}`)

  const idsOfCopiedDocs = await insertDocuments(targetCollection, sourceDocs)

  const targetDocs = await targetCollection.find({_id: {$in: idsOfCopiedDocs}})
  await deleteDocuments(sourceCollection, targetDocs)

  console.log('Done!')
}

async function insertDocuments (collection, documents) {
  const insertedIds = []
  const bulkWrites = []

  await documents.forEach(doc => {
    const {_id} = doc

    insertedIds.push(_id)
    bulkWrites.push({
      replaceOne: {
        filter: {_id},
        replacement: doc,
        upsert: true,
      },
    })
  })

  if (bulkWrites.length) await collection.bulkWrite(bulkWrites, {ordered: false})

  return insertedIds
}

async function deleteDocuments (collection, documents) {
  const bulkWrites = []

  await documents.forEach(({_id}) => {
    bulkWrites.push({
      deleteOne: {
        filter: {_id},
      },
    })
  })

  if (bulkWrites.length) await collection.bulkWrite(bulkWrites, {ordered: false})
}
```

Comment: Why are the `targetDocs` read from the `targetCollection` again? Does the bulk operation not return an error if anything goes wrong?

Comment: Just one typo in your script: L. 8 should become: const targetDocs = await sourceCollection.find({_id: {$in: idsOfCopiedDocs}}). You need docs from source collection to be deleted :)

Answer (score 5):

***First option (Using mongo dump)***

1.Get a dump from collection

mongodump -d db -c source_collection

2.Restore from collection

mongorestore -d db -c target_collection dir=dump/db_name/source_collection.bson

***Second Option***

Running aggregate

db.getCollection('source_collection').aggregate([ { $match: {"emailAddress" : "apitester@mailinator.com"} }, { $out: "target_collection" } ])

***Third Option (Slowest)***

Running a through for loop

db.getCollection('source_collection').find().forEach(function(docs){ db.getCollection('target_collection').insert(docs); }) print("Rolleback Completed!");

Answer (score 3):

May be from the performance point of view it's better to remove a lot of documents using one command(especially if you have indexes for query part) rather than deleting them one-by-one.

For example:

```
db.source.find({$gte: start, $lt: end}).forEach(function(doc){
   db.target.insert(doc);
});
db.source.remove({$gte: start, $lt: end});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a restatement of @Markus W Mahlberg

Returning the favor - as a function

```
function moveDocuments(sourceCollection,targetCollection,filter) {
    var bulkInsert = targetCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    var bulkRemove = sourceCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    sourceCollection.find(filter)
        .forEach(function(doc) {
        bulkInsert.insert(doc);
        bulkRemove.find({_id:doc._id}).removeOne();
        }
  )
  bulkInsert.execute();
  bulkRemove.execute();
}
```

An example use

```
var x = {dsid:{$exists: true}};
moveDocuments(db.pictures,db.artifacts,x)
```

to move all documents that have top level element dsid from the pictures to the artifacts collection

Answer (score 0):

From MongoDB 3.0 up, you can use the [copyTo](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/) command with the following syntax:

```
db.source_collection.copyTo("target_collection")
```

Then you can use the [drop](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.drop/) command to remove the old collection:

```
db.source_collection.drop()
```

Comment: `copyTo` is deprecated since version 3.0:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/ 
Moreover, it does not support filters.

Answer (score 0):

I do like the response from @markus-w-mahlberg, however at times, I have seen the need to keep it a bit simpler for people. As such I have a couple of functions that are below. You could naturally wrap thing here with bulk operators as he did, but this code works with new and old Mongo systems equally.

```
function parseNS(ns){
    //Expects we are forcing people to not violate the rules and not doing "foodb.foocollection.month.day.year" if they do they need to use an array.
    if (ns instanceof Array){
        database =  ns[0];
        collection = ns[1];
    }
    else{
        tNS =  ns.split(".");
        if (tNS.length > 2){
            print('ERROR: NS had more than 1 period in it, please pass as an [ "dbname","coll.name.with.dots"] !');
            return false;
        }
        database = tNS[0];
        collection = tNS[1];
    }
    return {database: database,collection: collection};
}

function insertFromCollection( sourceNS,  destNS, query, batchSize, pauseMS){
    //Parse and check namespaces
    srcNS = parseNS(sourceNS);
    destNS = parseNS(destNS);
    if ( srcNS == false ||  destNS == false){return false;}

    batchBucket = new Array();
    totalToProcess = db.getDB(srcNS.database).getCollection(srcNS.collection).find(query,{_id:1}).count();
    currentCount = 0;
    print("Processed "+currentCount+"/"+totalToProcess+"...");
    db.getDB(srcNS.database).getCollection(srcNS.collection).find(query).addOption(DBQuery.Option.noTimeout).forEach(function(doc){
        batchBucket.push(doc);
        if ( batchBucket.length > batchSize){
            db.getDB(destNS.database).getCollection(destNS.collection)insert(batchBucket);
            currentCount += batchBucket.length;
            batchBucket = [];
            sleep (pauseMS);
            print("Processed "+currentCount+"/"+totalToProcess+"...");       
        }
    }
    print("Completed");
}

/** Example Usage:
        insertFromCollection("foo.bar","foo2.bar",{"type":"archive"},1000,20);
```

You could obviously add a  `db.getSiblingDB(srcNS.database).getCollection(srcNS.collection).remove(query,true)`
If you wanted to also remove the records after they are copied to the new location. The code can easily be built like that to make it restartable.

Answer (score 0):

I had 2297 collection for 15 million of documents but some collection was empty.

Using only copyTo the script failed, but with this script optimization:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collname) {
    var c = db.getCollection(collname).count();
    if(c!==0){
      db.getCollection(collname).copyTo('master-collection');
      print('Copied collection ' + collname);
    }
});
```

all works fine for me.

NB: copyTo is deprecated because it block the read/write operation: so I think is fine if you know that the database is not usable during this operation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case for each didn't work. So I had to make some changes.

```
var kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String
});

var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);

var catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String
});

var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', catSchema);
```

This is Model for both the collection

```
`function Recursion(){
Kitten.findOne().lean().exec(function(error, results){
    if(!error){
        var objectResponse = results;
        var RequiredId = objectResponse._id;
        delete objectResponse._id;
        var swap = new Cat(objectResponse);
        swap.save(function (err) {
           if (err) {
               return err;
           }
           else {
               console.log("SUCCESSFULL");
               Kitten.deleteOne({ _id: RequiredId }, function(err) {
                if (!err) {
                        console.log('notification!');
                }
                else {
                        return err;
                }
            });
               Recursion();
           }
        });
    }
    if (err) {
        console.log("No object found");
        // return err;
    }
})
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mat Wills answer here comes the Typescript version thats fully working. It's based on NestJS. Following is the implementation from a service class:

```
...
async moveDocuments(
        sourceCollection: Model<any>,
        targetCollection: Model<any>,
        filter: any
    ) {
        const sourceDocs = await sourceCollection.find(filter)

        console.log(sourceDocs.length)

        console.log(
            `Moving ${await sourceDocs.length} documents from ${
                sourceCollection.modelName
            } to ${targetCollection.modelName}`
        )

        const idsOfCopiedDocs = await this.insertDocuments(
            targetCollection,
            sourceDocs
        ).catch((err) => {
            return Promise.reject(err)
        })

        const targetDocs = await sourceCollection.find({
            _id: { $in: idsOfCopiedDocs },
        })

        await this.deleteDocuments(sourceCollection, targetDocs).catch(
            (err) => {
                return Promise.reject(err)
            }
        )

        return Promise.resolve('Cleanups done!')
    }

    private async insertDocuments(
        collection: Model<any>,
        documents: Document[]
    ) {
        const insertedIds = []
        const bulkWrites = []

        await documents.forEach((doc) => {
            const { _id } = doc

            insertedIds.push(_id)
            bulkWrites.push({
                replaceOne: {
                    filter: { _id },
                    replacement: doc,
                    upsert: true,
                },
            })
        })

        if (bulkWrites.length)
            await collection.bulkWrite(bulkWrites, { ordered: false })

        return insertedIds
    }

    private async deleteDocuments(
        collection: Model<any>,
        documents: Document[]
    ) {
        const bulkWrites = []

        await documents.forEach(({ _id }) => {
            bulkWrites.push({
                deleteOne: {
                    filter: { _id },
                },
            })
        })

        if (bulkWrites.length)
            await collection.bulkWrite(bulkWrites, { ordered: false })
    }
```

And thats how you might call the service with the help of dayjs:

```
...
const now = dayjs()
const xMonthBeforeNow = now.subtract(5, 'months')
const filter = {
    createdAt: {
        $lte: date,
    }
},

const cleanupResult = await this.cleaningService.moveDocuments(
            this.anyModel,
            this.anyModelOld,
            filter
        )
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I planned to arhieve 1000 records at a time using bulkinsert and bulkdelete methods of pymongo.

For both source and target

1. create mongodb objects to connect to the database.
2. instantiate the bulk objects. Note: I created a backup of bulk objects too. This will help me to rollback the insertion or removal when an error occurs.
   example:

   For source

   `// replace this    with mongodb object creation logic 
   source_db_obj = db_help.create_db_obj(source_db, source_col)
   source_bulk = source_db_obj.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
   source_bulk_bak = source_db_obj.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()`

   For target

   `// replace this with mogodb object creation logic
   target_db_obj = db_help.create_db_obj(target_db, target_col) 
   target_bulk = target_db_obj.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
   target_bulk_bak = target_db_obj.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()`
3. Obtain the source records that matches the filter criteria

   source_find_results = source_db_obj.find(filter)
4. Loop through the source records

   create target and source bulk operations

   Append archived_at field with the current datetime to the target collection

   `//replace this with the logic to obtain the UTCtime.
   doc['archived_at'] = db_help.getUTCTime()
   target_bulk.insert(document)
   source_bulk.remove(document)`


   for rollback in case of any errors or exceptions, create target_bulk_bak and source_bulk_bak operations.

   `target_bulk_bak.find({'_id':doc['_id']}).remove_one()
   source_bulk_bak.insert(doc)
   //remove the extra column 
   doc.pop('archieved_at', None)`
5. When the record count to 1000, execute the target - bulk insertion and source - bulk removal. Note: this method takes target_bulk and source_bulk objects for execution.

   execute_bulk_insert_remove(source_bulk, target_bulk)
6. When exception occurs, execute the target_bulk_bak removal and source_bulk_bak inesertions. This would rollback the changes. Since mongodb doesn't have rollback, I came up with this hack

   execute_bulk_insert_remove(source_bulk_bak, target_bulk_bak)
7. Finally re-initialize the source and target bulk and bulk_bak objects. This is necessary because you can use them only once.
8. Complete code

   ```
       def execute_bulk_insert_remove(source_bulk, target_bulk):
           try:
               target_bulk.execute()
               source_bulk.execute()
           except BulkWriteError as bwe:
               raise Exception(
                   "could not archive document, reason:    {}".format(bwe.details))

       def archive_bulk_immediate(filter, source_db, source_col, target_db, target_col):
           """
           filter: filter criteria for backup
           source_db: source database name
           source_col: source collection name
           target_db: target database name
           target_col: target collection name
           """
           count = 0
           bulk_count = 1000

           source_db_obj = db_help.create_db_obj(source_db, source_col)
           source_bulk = source_db_obj.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
           source_bulk_bak = source_db_obj.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()

           target_db_obj = db_help.create_db_obj(target_db, target_col)
           target_bulk = target_db_obj.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
           target_bulk_bak = target_db_obj.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()

           source_find_results = source_db_obj.find(filter)

           start = datetime.now()

           for doc in source_find_results:
               doc['archived_at'] = db_help.getUTCTime()

               target_bulk.insert(doc)
               source_bulk.find({'_id': doc['_id']}).remove_one()
               target_bulk_bak.find({'_id': doc['_id']}).remove_one()
               doc.pop('archieved_at', None)
               source_bulk_bak.insert(doc)

               count += 1

               if count % 1000 == 0:
                   logger.info("count: {}".format(count))
                   try:
                       execute_bulk_insert_remove(source_bulk, target_bulk)
                   except BulkWriteError as bwe:
                       execute_bulk_insert_remove(source_bulk_bak, target_bulk_bak)
                       logger.info("Bulk Write Error: {}".format(bwe.details))
                       raise

                   source_bulk = source_db_obj.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
                   source_bulk_bak = source_db_obj.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()

                   target_bulk = target_db_obj.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
                   target_bulk_bak = target_db_obj.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()

           end = datetime.now()

           logger.info("archived {} documents to {} in ms.".format(
               count, target_col, (end - start)))
   ```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a minute to read through [answer] - this looks helpful but it would benefit from some explanation of what the code does, consider [edit]-ing that in?

Answer (score -2):

You build an index to search for all documents that should be archived existing within active Collections and then you use a MongoDB command to move the documents from its source to a target.

Comment: If this is an answer, please be explicit, provide the explicit code required to do this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).