# Insert all documents from one collection into another collection in MongoDB database

Tags: mongodb

I have a python script that collects data everyday and inserts it into a MongoDB collection (~10M documents). Sometimes the job fails and I am left with partial data which is not useful to me. I would like to insert the data into a staging collection first and then copy or move all documents from the staging collection into the final collection only when the job finishes and the data is complete. I cannot seem to find a straight forward solution for doing this as a "bulk" type operation, but it seems there should be one.

In SQL it would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO final_table
SELECT *
FROM staging_table
```

I thought that db.collection.copyTo() would work for this but it seems it makes the destination collection a clone of the source collection.

Additionally, I know from this: [mongodb move documents from one collection to another collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039083/mongodb-move-documents-from-one-collection-to-another-collection) that I can do something like the following:

```
var documentsToMove = db.collectionA.find({});
documentsToMove.forEach(function(doc) {
    db.collectionB.insert(doc);
}
```

But it seems like there should be a more efficient way.

So, How can I take all documents from one collection and insert them into another collection in the most efficient manner?

NOTE: the final collection has data in it already. The new documents that I want to move over would be adding to this data, e.g if my staging collection has 2 documents and my final collection has 10 documents, I would have 12 documents in my final collection after I move the staging data over.

Comment: you still want the original collection to exist?

Comment: Once I move the documents from the staging collection to the final collection, I do not need to persist the staging collection.

Comment: Use the method described in following topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039083

Answer (score 0):

You can use db.cloneCollection(); see [mondb cloneCollection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/)

Answer (score 0):

if you no longer need the staging collection you can simply use the renaming option.

```
 switch to admin db
db.runCommand({renameCollection:"staging.CollectionA",to:"targetdb.CollectionB"})
```

Comment: I want to move the documents from one collection into an existing collection that already has data in it. I.e. I want to append one collection to another. I have updated the question to clarify this.