# Mongodb back up old data then remove it from database periodically

Tags: mongodb

I have a project that currently stores GPS tracking data in MongoDB, and it grows really fast. In order to slow it down, I want to automatically backup old data then remove it from the database monthly. The old data must older than 3 months.

Is there any solution to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

This question was [partially answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039083/mongodb-move-documents-from-one-collection-to-another-collection/27041518#27041518) earlier.

After using this approach, you can backup the collection with your old data using [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump) for example:

```
mongodump -host yourhost [-u user] -d yourdb -c collOldDocs
```