# Performing Data Cleanup In Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, coffeescript

My application tracks the movements of data throughout the system. When a movement is recorded it is placed in a separate collection that determines whether the document is enroute, available or out of service. I used $addToSet to place the _id, and $pullAll to make sure that when a doc is moved from enroute to available, it is not duplicated. But when the _id is moved to a new location entirely, I need to remove the old data from the old location and insert it into the new location. The insertion works but I cannot figure out how to properly remove the data from the old location. These are all down within Meteor Calls and Mongodb

```
          if last.status is "Enroute"
            LastLocation.update locationId: last.locationId,partId: last.partId,
                $addToSet:
                    enroutePurchaseIds: lastPurchaseId
                $pullAll:
                    availiblePurchaseIds: lastPurchaseId
                    outOfServicePurchaseIds: lastPurchaseId
```

Comment: ` The insertion works but I cannot figure out how to properly remove the data from the old location` does this refer to the `$pullAll` operation? Can you add some short set of sample data, the current result and the expected result?

Comment: Since, you are using the `$pull` and `$addToSet`, this means you are maintaining these data _id's in arrays (within documents). You know the `_id` value of the tracked document, and the _old location_ (this must be a field within the document where the dat is tracked). So, you can query that document and update it ($pull is an update operation). _"... but I cannot figure out how to properly remove the data from the old location."_ can you share this issue in little more detail?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

You can run the merge command from upcoming 4.4 version which allows updating the same collection the aggregation is running on. Pass the array as old location and new location

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"location":{"$in":[oldLocation,newLocation]}}},
  {"$addFields":{"sortOrder":{"$indexOfArray":[[oldLocation,newLocation],"$location"]}}},
  {"$sort":{"sortOrder":1}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":null,
    "oldLocationDoc":{"$first":"$$ROOT"},
    "newLocationDoc":{"$last":"$$ROOT"}
  }},
  {"$addFields":{
    "oldLocationDoc.old":{
      "$filter":{
        "input":"$oldLocationDoc.old",
        "cond":{"$ne":["$$this",oldLocation]}
      }
    },
    "newLocationDoc.new":{"$concatArrays":["$newLocationDoc.new",[newLocation]]}
  }},
  {"$project":{"locations":["$oldLocationDoc","$newLocationDoc"]}},
  {"$unwind":"$locations"},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$locations"}},
  {"$merge":{
    "into":{"db":"db","coll":"collection"},
    "on":"_id",
    "whenMatched":"merge",
    "whenNotMatched":"failed"
  }}
]
```

**Original**

Not possible to move array/field value from one document to another document in a single update operation.

You would want to use [`transactions`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) to perform multi document updates in a atomic way. Requires replica set.

```
var session = db.getMongo().startSession();
var collection = session.getDatabase('test').getCollection('collection');
session.startTransaction({readConcern: {level:'snapshot'},writeConcern: {w:'majority'}});
collection.update({location:oldLocation},{$pull:{availiblePurchaseIds:lastPurchaseId}});
collection.update({location:newLocation},{$push:{enroutePurchaseIds:lastPurchaseId}});
session.commitTransaction()
session.endSession()
```

Other options would be to perform [`bulk`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/index.html) updates in case of standalone mongod instance.

```
var bulk = db.getCollection('collection').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find({location:oldLocation}).updateOne({$pull:{availiblePurchaseIds:lastPurchaseId}});
bulk.find({location:newLocation}).updateOne({$push:{enroutePurchaseIds:lastPurchaseId}});  
bulk.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you moving the entire document from one collection to another or just moving the document's id? I can't help much with coffeescript but if you're looking to move entire documents you might find the following thread helpful.

[mongodb move documents from one collection to another collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039083/mongodb-move-documents-from-one-collection-to-another-collection/41483981#41483981)

Comment: Thanks for the article but no I am not moving one document from on collection to another. I am moving Id's from one document to another. When the id is placed into another document I need it removed from the document it was coming from.