# Move one element/document in a mongoDb collection to another collection within the same Database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

Ok, so what I'm doing is using the MERN stack with mongoose, I'm creating a project of a news site, where I have two different types of news: the new ones or recent news, which I would like to order chronologically, and then the archived news section, this is where you would archive the old news that you don't want to see on the news page anymore.

The thing is that I have 2 models: news, and archived. They are the same (same type, same structure, same info) but they are different documents, as one is for the archived news and the other for the recent ones.

In order to have the archived views page with information news, I want to place a button on the news where it says "archive", and MOVE the selected notice to the archived section. My problem comes from the backend, I'm trying to figure out what would be approach to take in order to create a route with node.js and express where I could move the notice from the NEWS collection to the ARCHIVED collection.

I may be looking in the wrong place and maybe I'm supposed to do this on the client side (React), but I'm a bit lost and looking for some guidance as to how could i MOVE them, NOT COPY THEM, BUT MOVE them to the other collection.  Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use triggers?

Comment: please explain a bit better? although my whole point its to have the functionality of the button to pass it on manually

Answer (score 0):

Better use a batch / daemon, that will  move all documents older than 1 month /  1 week automatically https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule or a general button click to archive the OLD records (in past 1 month / 1 week)

Ref 1: [mongodb move documents from one collection to another collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039083/mongodb-move-documents-from-one-collection-to-another-collection/41483981#41483981)
Ref 2 : [mongodb move documents from one collection to another collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039083/mongodb-move-documents-from-one-collection-to-another-collection)

Code snippet :

```
let bulkInsert = db.target.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
let bulkRemove = db.source.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
let date = new Date()
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() -1)
db.source.find({"yourDateField":{$lt: date}}).forEach(
    function(doc){
      bulkInsert.insert(doc);
      bulkRemove.find({_id:doc._id}).removeOne();
    }
  )
bulkInsert.execute()
bulkRemove.execute()
```

Comment: i dont want them to move automatically but on command, with a button.

Comment: Ok do the same  above code snippet but filter with id and insert to another db source and remove from current source.